# Passing a pointer by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int *& toMerge, int lo, int mid, int hi)
{
    int merged[hi+1];
    int i = lo, j = mid+1;
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
    {
        if (i > mid) {merged[k] = toMerge[j]; j++;}
        else if (j > hi) {merged[k] = toMerge[i]; i++;}
        else if (toMerge[j] < toMerge[i]) {merged[k] = toMerge[j]; j++;}
        else {merged[k] = toMerge[i]; i++;}
    }
    toMerge = merged;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int x[8] = {1,7,4,6,2,7,3,2};
    merge(x, 0, 7, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to pass a pointer by reference here such that the end result will be that the array `x` will be sorted. However, my compiler is throwing an error that there is no matching function call for the `merge(x, 0, 7, 3)`.

I am not sure as to why this is happening because the merge function requires a pointer, and `x` is a pointer to the first element in the array -- so it should work. Why doesn't it?

Comment: `x` is an array, not a pointer.

Comment: Shouldn't `merge(&x[0], 0, 7, 3);` also work?

Comment: @KristerAndersson I already tried that -- didn't work

Comment: @chris But doesn't `x` give you a pointer to the first element?

Comment: @user2612743, `x` *decays* into a pointer to the first element. See [arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c). While I'm talking, I should point out that `int merged[hi+1];` is invalid because the size is not a compile time constant.

Comment: How would I pass it as a reference to a pointer? Doing &x[0] doesn't work? And if I'm not mistaken C++11 added support for declaring those types of arrays.

Comment: @user2612743, You need a pointer in `main` that is an lvalue (like a separate variable). Or you can change it to use `std::vector` (since the function won't work properly with `std::array` without some changes). Anyway, `&x[0]` is not an lvalue. It's a nameless temporary, which can't bind to a reference (it gets destroyed at the end of the function call anyway, so there's no point). And C++11 did not. Not even C++14. Compile with `-pedantic`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array decays to a pointer when you pass it as an argument to a function call but not to a reference to a pointer.

Imagine this:

```
void foo(int*& p)
{
   p = new int;
}

int main()
{
   int arr[6] = {0};

    foo(arr);
   // You don't want arr to be an invalid object here.
   // If the compiler allowed you to do that, that's what will happen.
   // Not only that, foo(arr); is equivalent to:
   // arr = new int;
   // which is not allowed in the language.
}
```

Comment: How would you explicitly pass it as a reference?

Comment: You can't. You have to ask yourself whether you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You really should NOT pass a reference, because you don't really want `merge` changing the value of the pointer. You just want to allow it to change the values stored in the array, which it can do without the reference (i.e., just from the pointer).

Comment: Except I need an auxiliary array for mergesort and copying the elements back takes addition O(n) time.

Comment: Huh? The array values are not copied when passing either a pointer, or a pointer to reference, or a reference to a pointer, or a reference.

Comment: No, `merge()` has a syntactically correct signature. `T*&` is a reference to a pointer, not a pointer to a reference.

Comment: I know -- if I were to just use a pointer and change the values stored in the array, I would have to update each value in the array with the sorted values, taking O(n) time.

Comment: Another issue is that int merged[hi+1]; has local scope and you try to return it via a pointer. That pointer will then point to deallocated memory.

Comment: @XavierLeclercq True -- how does C++'s sort() handle this?

Comment: @0x499602D2, well, silly me. Thanks. Not sure where my head was.

Comment: @user2612743, It sorts in place. And there's no sort that takes O(n) time in general, so something being O(n) isn't really anything to worry about.